# Why eclipse does not find my features?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I have written some eclipse plugins and consolidated them in featues. If the features does only contain plugins all is ok. But if I include a feature to a feature then I get the following error:

```
Unable to find feature "<featureName>" with version in range [2.6.0,2.6.1).
```

where featuerName is the including feature. I tinkered with the version numbers of the included feature without success.

here comes the including feature.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature
      id="de.mdsd.xtext.support.validator.model.sdk"
      label="Xtext Support Validator Generator Feature"
      version="2.6.0.qualifier"
      provider-name="XXX Software">

   <description>
      This plugin provides a small DSL for describing and generating an Xtext validator class.
   </description>

   <includes
         id="de.mdsd.xtext.support.sdk.sdk"
         version="[2.6.1,3.0.0)"/>

   <requires>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.xtext"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.equinox.common" version="3.5.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore" version="2.10.2" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="de.mdsd.xtext.swtch.model" version="2.0.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.xtext.util"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.emf.ecore"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.emf.common"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib"/>
      <import plugin="org.antlr.runtime"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.xtext.common.types"/>
      <import plugin="org.apache.log4j"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.xtext.ui"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui.editors" version="3.5.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui.ide" version="3.5.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.xtext.ui.shared"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.xtext.builder"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.ui"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.xtext.ui.codetemplates.ui"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.compare"/>
      <import plugin="de.mdsd.xtext.support.sdk" version="2.1.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="de.mdsd.xtext.up.name.providerswitch.model" version="1.4.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
   </requires>

   <plugin
         id="de.mdsd.xtext.support.validator.model"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="de.mdsd.xtext.support.validator.model.ui"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

</feature>
```

here comes the included feature.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature
      id="de.mdsd.xtext.support.sdk.sdk"
      label="Xtext Support Feature"
      version="2.6.1.qualifier"
      provider-name="MDSD Software">

   <description url="http://www.example.com/description">
      This is a collection of classes that support the development
of Xtext generated tools.

Now it contains switches and name providers for GenModel-, Ecore models and Xtext grammars.
   </description>

   <copyright url="http://www.example.com/copyright">
      Copyright Olaf Bigalk 2013
   </copyright>

   <license url="http://www.example.com/license">
      EPL
   </license>

   <requires>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.emf.ecore" version="2.9.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.xtext" version="2.4.2" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.xtend.lib"/>
      <import plugin="com.google.guava"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.xtext.ui" version="2.4.3" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.jdt.core" version="3.9.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.xtend.typesystem.emf" version="1.4.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.xtext.xbase" version="2.8.3" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.emf" version="2.6.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
   </requires>

   <plugin
         id="de.mdsd.xtext.support.sdk"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version=""
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="de.mdsd.xtext.support.xtend.utils"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version=""
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="de.mdsd.xtext.support.xbase.utils"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version=""
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="de.mdsd.xtext.support.utils"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version=""
         unpack="false"/>

</feature>
```

What is the reason for this error ?

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information here to say anything. Show us the feature.xml for the including and included features. How are you installing these features?

Comment: Thanks for taking time to investigate my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a version range like `[2.6.1,3.0.0)` in the `includes` element of a `feature.xml`.

Either specify the exact version of the feature to be included (`2.6.1.qualifier`) or specify `0.0.0` to not check the version.